# Showing sequence is Cauchy in L^1 norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n,&\text{if }0\le x<\frac{1}{2}\\\\
1,&\text{if } \frac{1}{2}\le x\le 1\;.
\end{cases}$$

Then clearly $(f_n)$ is sequence in $C[0,1]$. I need to show this is cauchy sequence in $C[0,1]$ with $L^1$ norm.

**My attempt**  By definition of cauchy sequence, i think we need establish

$||f_n-f_m||<\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $m, n$

i.e. $\int^{1}_0 |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|dx<\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $m, n$

But,

$\int^{1}_0 |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|dx\\
=\int^{1/2}_0 |(x+1/2)^n-(x+1/2)^m|dx$

(Since on $[1/2,1]$ both $f_n$, $f_m$ are equal for all $m, n$ )

In next step i had used traingle inequality and spit the integral into two parts and obtained,

$\int^{1}_0 |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|dx\\
≤\int^{1/2}_0 |(x+1/2)^n| dx+\int^{1/2}_0 |(x+1/2)^m| dx$\
$=\frac{1}{n+1}[1-(1/2)^{n+1}]+\frac{1}{m+1}[1-(1/2)^{m+1}]$

But i am unable to obtain conclusion

Further, i like to know is there is any direct approach to conclude it is Cauchy sequence?

Comment: Use the triangle inequality, split up the integral using linearity, and evaluate those integrals. You should be able to calculate them explicitly.

Comment: @Oiler sir, i used traingle inequality,  but, unable to show it is less than $\epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be fixed. Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{1/2} \left| (x + 1/2)^n - (x + 1/2)^m \right| \, dx & \leq & \int_{0}^{1/2}  \left| (x + 1/2)^n \right| \, dx + \int_{0}^{1/2}  \left| (x + 1/2)^n \right| \, dx \\
& = & \left[\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{(1/2)^{n+1}}{n + 1} \right] + \left[ \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{(1/2)^{m+1}}{m + 1} \right]\\
& < & \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m}. 
\end{eqnarray*}
From here, can you determine what constraints you must put on $n$ (resp. $m$) so tha $\dfrac{1}{n} < \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$?

Comment: Sir, How to obtain last inequality, $<\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi The terms in the numerator with powers of 1/2 are both negative and $\dfrac{1}{n+1} < \dfrac{1}{n}$

Comment: Is that, mean $=\frac{1}{n+1}[1-(1/2)^{n+1}]+\frac{1}{m+1}[1-(1/2)^{m+1}]≤\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{m+1}<\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}$

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Yes.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your help. I like to know, is there is any direct approach to conclude sequence is Cauchy in this space? Otherwise we need to check by definition, for each of Sequence in this space.

Comment: I’m not really sure I’m understanding your question correctly, but this is a direct proof. If you want to show a sequence is Cauchy, you have to show that it satisfies the definition.